# scrolling toolbar is not hiding when i scroll in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Im trying to hide my toolbar on scroll down , but i cant able to find the problem
i have used

> android.support:design:24.2.1
>
> android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1

can you find any bug in my code that code be helpful

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mako.movietake.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
       
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="1.5dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> mainactivity.java

```
 viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new sliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));
    tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

> a tab fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    >
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView_cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have listview inside viewpager?

Comment: i have text view inside scroll view

Comment: Can you post layout of one of `ViewPager`'s view who has scroll view and is scrolling. And `Activity` code where you used this layout?

Comment: You need to add scroll flags to scroll view

Comment: @MohammedAtif  i used these flags still not working
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

Comment: @JimitPatel i did can u check it out now

Comment: Try using `NestedScrollView` instead https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: @MohammedAtif i have made few changes in my code can u help me now

Comment: remove everything amd replace with one single recyclerview